# Strengthen normal (bump) map in Blender Internal rendering engine?

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, normal-map

Is there a way to do this in Blender Internal rendering engine with a normal map already set up and good to go? Specifically when the model has nodes enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Main control is the Normal value in the Geometry section of the influence tab in the texture properties panel. Other than that, you can play with the contrast control of the texture slot.

[image]

Comment: I increased the contrast and tampered the "Normal" in Geometry respectively; the render stays exactly the same as before, strength unaffected.

Comment: Then there should be some other problem, I think you should upload your file, to get analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

this could be where you have to change the strenght, idk much about blender internal but this node works in both renderers [image]